# Chromium / typescript expecting source maps in different location

Tags: typescript, electron, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, source-maps

I'm building an Electron desktop app (which uses Chromium) with Typescript. The Chromium dev tools seem to be looking in the wrong place for source maps.

I'm on Windows, and the application is served using `file://`

The generated files have the source map location relative to the location of the .js file. For example `/myapp/dist/components/loginview.js` has `sourceMappingURL=loginview.js.map`, and the mapping file is located in the same directory as the JS file.

Chromium, however, is looking for the mapping file in the root of the application (alongside the currently loaded HTML file). For the above example, it emits this warning:

```
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: file:///myapp/dist/loginview.js.map
```

In this case, I would expect dev tools to look in "file:///myapp/dist/**components**/loginview.js.map" instead.

I've tried various options in tsconfig.json, including mapRoot and rootDir, but nothing seems to change the generated URL.

I'm not sure if the solution lies in configuring typescript to emit the subfolder name in the source mapping URL, or configuring chromium to resolve the URL relative to the js file. I have been unable to find a way to do either.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @Dominic I'm afraid not, sorry